# Apache DAV at `/` with normal hosting at `/foo` - how?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-dav-svn

Should I not be able to have a configuration where I serve SVN repos with `SVNParentPath` at `<Location />` and then override DAV and host normal files using another location `<Location /foo>`? I wish to host my XSLT files on the same subdomain and still host repos at root. Of course, if I was to have a repo called foo, that would not be accessible, and that's ok.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    #Host XSLT files here
    <Location /foo>
        DAV Off
    </Location>

    #Host my repos relative to root, such as /my_repo/
    <Location />
        DAV svn     
        SVNParentPath "myrepos"
        SVNListParentPath on
        SVNIndexXSLT "/foo/my.xsl"
        ...
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But DAV SVN still looks for a repo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D:error xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:m="http://apache.org/dav/xmlns" xmlns:C="svn:">
<C:error/>
<m:human-readable errcode="720003">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

Edit:
I read up on mod rewrite a bit and so far as I understand it the target path of a rewrite rule can only be local unless you use redirect `[R]`. This for example works, it creates a redirect (HTTP 302):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*)$ http://someotherhost/foo/$1 [R]
```

However, it still doesn't work with `SVNIndexXSLT`. Probably because it doesn't follow redirects.

Answer (score 1):

"[Note, that once you have DAV enabled for some location, it *cannot* be disabled for sublocations.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html#dav)" (emphasis theirs)

You can try mod_rewriting your way out of this one.  If you had a

```
RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*)$ /some/local/directory/$1 [L]
```

Theoretically that *might* evade DAV, since without the PT flag it shouldn't hand the request off to any other module.  Worth a shot, at least.

If it doesn't work, be sure to reply to this so someone else trying this will see that it can't be done ;)

Comment: Ok, I've tried it and it works, sort of. But not with SVNIndexXSLT. See my edited question for details.

Comment: @mandrake: My guess is that SVNIndexXSLT is used by mod_svn_dav internally so it needs to be stored locally.  Maybe you could make a separate /xslt folder and use /foo for everything else?

Comment: You mean to have the repos served under `/repos/*`? Yeah, that would work, but I was trying to avoid it. And if I had the repos there I wouldn't need the rewrite either since DAV can be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Simply host svn at svn.example.com, and keep / for normal http.

Comment: Do you mean to host at svn.example.com/svn and root for normal hosting? I wanted to avoid that solution. Or do you mean to configure SVNIndexXSLT to point at another host? Because that's not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever work out an answer to this? I happen to be trying the exact same configuration right now and I'm running into the same problem as you.

For what it's worth there is half a solution for you - provided the ability to automatically list repositories (with SVNListParentPath On) isn't critical to you.

You could use the SVNPath directive instead - thus you would have something like:

```
<Location />
     SVNIndexXSLT "/repos-web/view/repos.xsl"
     # Other common options, such as Auth options can go here
</Location>

<Location /repository1>
     SVNPath /var/lib/svn/repositories/repo1
     DAV svn
</Location>

<Location /repository2>
     SVNPath /var/lib/svn/repositories/repo2
     DAV svn
</Location>

<Location /repository3>
     SVNPath /var/lib/svn/repositories/repo3
     DAV svn
</Location>
```

Obviously, if you're running a setup where you create new repositories regularly (repository per project approach) then this won't be very appealing to you. But it'll do for a small, fixed, number of repositories.

You could then drop a hard coded index.htm in the apache document root if you wanted something user friendly to appear at http://svn.yourdomain.com/

I've tested this approach and it works. Shame about losing the auto-generated list of repositories though (and having to map each repository in the httpd.conf)